# Transform decimal number to percentage and integer python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, percentage

I have a column that I need to transform its value to percentage.

example
I have the value 0.166978 and I need to transform it into 16.70%

I did it as follows

```
df['EXAMPLE'] = df[['EXAMPLE']].applymap("{:.4f}%".format)
```

and got

0.1670%

How do I change these decimal places
to get 16.70%

When I multiply by some value eg 10, 100 it looks like this
0.1670%0.1670%0.1670%0.1670%0.1670%0.1670%0.16...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
df['EXAMPLE'] = df['EXAMPLE'].apply(lambda row:"{:.2%}".format(float(row))
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try this :

```
df['EXAMPLE'] = (df['EXAMPLE']*100).apply(lambda r:"{:.2%}".format(r))
```